# ckan unpacking error during local install

Tags: ckan

I've been tasked with installing CKAN on a server that cannot connect to any external sites directly (or via proxies due to work security policy).

All the required rpms are installed usign local installs, or via a RH Satellite server on the same network, or via pip install .

A colleague provided all the rpms/tar files and ckan-master.zip file to install - he has successfully used them to install ckan on an identical server, but Im not having much luck!

Here is the error im receiving:

```
> (pyenv)[root@bmdev-dl-svr07 ~]# pip install /tmp/ckan-master.zip Unpacking /tmp/ckan-master.zip   Running setup.py egg_info for package
> from file:///tmp/ckan-master.zip
>     warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'ckanext/*/i18n'
>     no previously-included directories found matching '.git'
>     warning: no files found matching 'CHANGELOG.txt'
>     warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'ckan_deb' Cleaning up...*
```

I've checked the ckan-master.zip file and indeed there are no ckanext/*/i18n or ckan_deb directories - does this suggest an issue with the provided zip file? or that I may be missing an rpm or other package?

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

CKAN is tricky to install if you deviate from the documented "cookbook" methods.  Do you have access such that you could create an RPM from the identical machine where CKAN has already been successfully installed?